# assigning multiple values to one dataframe from another based on a key

Tags: python, dataframe

I got some problem with joining DFs.

I got a sample dataframe *main*:

| id | some another columns... | key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ... | 3451 |
| 1 | ... | 7126 |
| 2 | ... | 6318 |

... and *second* one :

| id | key | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3451 | value1 |
| 1 | 3451 | value2 |
| 2 | 7126 | value3 |

I'd like to achieve the following output in *main*:

| id | some another columns... | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ... | value1, value2 |
| 1 | ... | value3 |
| 2 | ... |  |

I recieved above output by using apply() on *main* DF with function using .isin(). But i think it is  ineffective. Any other ideas how to achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Set the key as the index in df1 and use join

```
df.set_index('key').join(df2.groupby('key')['values'].agg(list))

      id some another columns...            values
key                                               
3451   0                     ...  [value1, value2]
7126   1                     ...          [value3]
6318   2                     ...               NaN
```

What happens with duplicate values in the key column of df?

```
      id some another columns...            values
key                                               
3451   0                     ...  [value1, value2]
3451   3                     ...  [value1, value2]
6318   2                     ...               NaN
7126   1                     ...          [value3]
```

Comment: Ok but what if values in key column in *main*  DF is not unique too

Comment: Then it wouldn't be a "key," which by definition is unique. However the values would just be applied to both duplicate keys.